# Selenium much slower in Firefox than Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a very simple selenium test the completes a login form. Using the ChromeDriver it completes in around 5 seconds, but using FirefoxDriver it takes around 30 seconds, with a multiple second pause between each step of the code.

My C# code is:

```
var browser = "firefox";
if (browser == "firefox")
{
    var options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
    options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager;
    _driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
}
else // Chrome
{
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
    _driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
_driver.Url = "...";
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys(username);
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys(password);
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"][value=\"" + JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode(buttonLabel) + "\"]")).Click();
_driver.Title.Should().Be(pageTitle);
_driver.Dispose();
```

I have tried both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Firefox, but it made no difference.

How can I debug where the pause is coming from?

Comment: Which version of FirefoxDriver are you using? I've found that can make a difference if you are not using the FirefoxDriver version that corresponds to the Firefox version.

Comment: Latest full releases of both - Firefox 89.0.1 and GeckoDriver 0.29.1

Comment: Are you sure the performance problem is not the browser itself? Try profiling the pages in the browser to see if Firefox is performing slower than Chrome. I suspect this has nothing to do with the web driver. Remember that Chrome implements many things that are emerging web standards or simply non-standard, which could include things that enhance performance -- not judging this as bad or good. Just be aware that your "web driver" problem might be a sign of the new, silent browser wars.

Comment: I can click go on the test, then open up my own copy of Firefox and manually complete the scripted steps and return to Visual Studio before the scripted test has finished. It's taking 10 seconds to start Firefox and load my log in screen. Then 5 seconds to find and complete the username field, 5 seconds for password and 5 seconds to click submit. It feels like something is timing out before it can continue to the next step.